# Orthogonal vectors with rationally independent components!

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Can I select 4 orthogonal vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$, where all of their components are rationally independent?

Comment: You have my permission.

Comment: What do you mean by "all of their components are rationally independent"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may take the rows of
$$
\pmatrix{
1        & \pi      & \pi^2    & \pi^3\\
\pi^5    &-\pi^4    & \pi^7    &-\pi^6\\
\pi^{10} & \pi^{11} &-\pi^8    &-\pi^9\\
\pi^{15} &-\pi^{14} &-\pi^{13} & \pi^{12}}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

How about (1 1 1 1), ($\pi$ $-\pi$ $\pi$ $-\pi$), ($e$ $e$ $-e$ $-e$), and ($\varphi$ $-\varphi$ $-\varphi$ $\varphi$)?

Comment: The components of $(1,1,1,1)$ are not rationally independent. (It is not clear whether this is what OP means)

Comment: Oh, he wants independence within in vector, not across corresponding components of each vector.

Comment: That's my interpretation, but only Meemo knows for sure.

Comment: I need rational independence of all components, within each vector and between the different vectors as well.

Comment: So you want rational independence in both ways and mutual orthogonality?

Comment: How about this. First, we randomly choose vector (the components of the vector are independently drawn from some random distribution) in $\mathbb{R}_4$, call it $P_1$. Then, we randomly choose a vector from the null (orthogonal) space of $P_1$, call it $P_2$. Then, we randomly choose a vector $P_3$ from the null space of span$\{P_1,P_2\}$, and so on. Is this generating vectors with rationally independent components?

Comment: Yes, I need mutual orthogonality and rational independence of the components.